# Trouble calling Javascript function within markup

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble getting my Javascript to run.

My javascript is located within the body tag of my master file (the layout page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var cssdropdown = {
        startchrome2: function() {
             document.getElementById("P3").innerHTML = "3 is complete"; 
        }
   }

</script>
```

I am attempting to call the startchrome2 function as follows:

```
<body onload="cssDropDown.startchrome2()">
```

The element I am attempting to access in my getElementById call is also located within the body:

```
<p id="P3">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

It is currently displaying "This is a paragraph". Why is my javascript failing to change it to "3 is complete"?

I've been fooling around with this for a while and it's quite frustrating. I'm sure it's a stupid error.

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 and the following are the declarations  at the top of the page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs"
    Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  
    TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your casing is wrong, try:

```
<body onload="cssdropdown.startchrome2()">
```

Comment: Well I feel like a moron, thanks for saving me what probably would have amounted to several further hours.